# How to compute homology group of $S^1 \times S^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to compute homology  group of $S^1 \times S^n$

what I try is to use mayer vietories sequence,but can someone help me to show in details?

Comment: Maybe look at the Kunneth Formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

Comment: Could this problem be done without help of Kunneth theorem?

Comment: What do you get if you write $S^n = A \cup B$ as two disk intersectings along the equator (which has the homology of $S^{n-1}$) and write the Mayer-Vietoris sequence ? Most term should be zero in the sequence.

Comment: I don't do too much AT yet, but with coefficients in $\Bbb Z$ it's $H_0\cong H_1\cong H_n\cong H_{n+1}\cong \Bbb Z^2$ and all else zero, is that right?